# How can i print unique value of particular column and then print rest of the columns in next line

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I want to do tsv file processing using awk,
Here's my input:

```
scaffold1   1   100 
scaffold1   101 200
scaffold1   201 300
scaffold2   1   100
scaffold2   201 500
scaffold3   10  500
scaffold4   10  300
```

Desired_output:

```
Feature scaffold1
1   100
101 200
201 300
Feature scaffold2
1   100
01  500
Feature scaffold3
10  500
Feature scaffold4
10  300
```

I tried using uniq and sort and also awk for printing uniq of first column using command
`awk '!seen[$1]++ Input.txt`
but it prints all unique values from first column and then i can print rest of the columns, but i want to print first unique value and rest columns in the next line, as shown above.

Please tell me is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '!seen[$1]++ {print "Feature",$1} {print $2,$3}' file
Feature scaffold1
1 100
101 200
201 300
Feature scaffold2
1 100
201 500
Feature scaffold3
10 500
Feature scaffold4
10 300
```

Answer (score 0):

i Have done this by using combination of sed and awk tested  and its works fine

code:

---

```
for o in `awk '{print $1}' example.txt| sort | uniq `; do sed -n "/$o/p" example.txt | sed "s/$o//g" |sed "1i Feature $o"; done
```

---

output

---

```
Feature  scaffold1
 1   100
  101 200
  201 300
Feature  scaffold2
  1   100
  201 500
Feature  scaffold3
  10  500
Feature  scaffold4
  10  300
```

---